# Immutable JS map or list

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

Say we have a plain javascript array of objects

```
[
  {id : 1, name : "Hartford Whalers"}, 
  {id : 2, name : "Toronto Maple Leafs"}, 
  {id : 3, name : "New York Rangers"}
]
```

and we wanted to bring it in to immutablejs. Would it be most natural to make it into a map or a list, and how would we update a property in one of the objects? Say change the name of "Hartford Whalers" to "Carolina Hurricanes".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should create a List of Maps for this. Immutable.js has a function `Immutable.fromJS` that will recursively convert JS Arrays to `Immutable.List` and JS Objects to `Immutable.Map`.

```
var input = [
  {id : 1, name : "Hartford Whalers"}, 
  {id : 2, name : "Toronto Maple Leafs"}, 
  {id : 3, name : "New York Rangers"}
];

var list = Immutable.fromJS(input);

list.toString(); // => "List [ Map { "id": 1, "name": "Hartford Whalers" }, Map { "id": 2, "name": "Toronto Maple Leafs" }, Map { "id": 3, "name": "New York Rangers" } ]"
```

You can set the name of the first item using `.setIn`:

```
var list2 = list.setIn([0, "name"], "Carolina Hurricanes");

list2.toString(); // => "List [ Map { "id": 1, "name": "Carolina Hurricanes" }, Map { "id": 2, "name": "Toronto Maple Leafs" }, Map { "id": 3, "name": "New York Rangers" } ]"
```

You can set the name of any item with name = "Hartford Whalers" to "Carolina Hurricanes" :

```
var list3 = list.map(function(item) {
  if(item.get("name") == "Hartford Whalers") {
    return item.set("name", "Carolina Hurricanes");
  } else {
    return item;
  }
});

list3.toString(); // => "List [ Map { "id": 1, "name": "Carolina Hurricanes" }, Map { "id": 2, "name": "Toronto Maple Leafs" }, Map { "id": 3, "name": "New York Rangers" } ]"
```

Comment: Ok great, thanks! If we don't know the index - how do we find it?

Comment: You mean find and update any item with name = "Hartford Whalers"?

Comment: Yeah, or maybe by id, but same same.

Comment: Please check my edit. You should be able to adapt it work with id.

Answer (score 1):

I disagree.

The example you give each element of the array is an object that has an `{ id }` property. One would assume you will want to access the elements of this array via their id. thats what ids are for.

Yes the native structure is a `List` of `Maps`. Although what you want is a `Map` of `Maps`.

#### Why?

Think about what you will need to do to retrieve `{ id: 1928, "Some Team" }`. You would have to iterate *one-by-one* through the list till you found your matching Id.

A *far more efficient* way to do this is create a map so you can directly "pluck" your object e.g.

```
const input = Immutable.fromJS({
  1: {id : 1, name : "Hartford Whalers"}, 
  2: {id : 2, name : "Toronto Maple Leafs"}, 
  3: {id : 3, name : "New York Rangers"},
  // ...
  1928: {id : 1928, name : "Some Team"},
});
```

Then to access it all you have to do is:

```
const team = input.get('1928');
```

you need to do the initial conversion, do that server-side if its coming from an API, its called normalisation. It has the benefit of saving data as well.

This is actually where the term "map" comes from

Comment: "One would assume you will want to access the elements of this array via their id." OP does want to access the elements, but by "name" (as mentioned in the question), which storing this in a Map wouldn't help over storing in a List. (Came here from the downvote.)

Comment: @Dogbert actually not meaning to be picky, but the op never said they wanted to select an item by name. It would be an odd design decision to do so, its more likely that the Op would select via Id them mod the name. There fore i stand by my claim. :-)

Comment: Yes, you're right. But if I'm even more picky, OP had a list in JS originally and did not want to access them by ID at all :). Also, I've never used ImmutableJS, but will storing this in a map lose the order? Can I iterate through the map while keeping the original order of the items in the array if the ids are not continous (which is extremely likely in the real data)?

Comment: @Dogbert yes it has many different types that address this issue. `Map` orders as a normal JS object, `OrderedMap` guarantees the order, although with a very very very slight performance decrease, `Lists`, `Seq` and other methods also preserve the order. the performance win you get form accessing a map over iteration is so much larger then `OrderedMap` usually I opt for that.